# How do I format a table like shown in C

Tags: c, format

I have to print numbers like so

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdQZT.png)

The assignment "The rst number is printed right-justified in 5 spaces then a colon
is printed then then number of steps is written as a left justified number in 5 spaces"

The code I have now prints numbers like so

```
    3:7    4:2    5:5    6:8    7:16    8:3    9:19   10:6
   11:14   12:9   13:9   14:17   15:17   16:4   17:12
   18:20   19:20   20:7
```

This is the code to print that table.

```
void makeTable(int start, int end) {
  for(int i = 0; i<=end-start; i++) {
    printf("%5d:%d", i+start, hofpo(i+start));
    if(i>0 && i % 7 == 0) {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

How do I print the numbers in the format that is needed?

Comment: With `%2d:%-3d"` and appropriate spacing added between each set of 6 characters. Or similar, the `%2d` formats to the right of a 2-space field, the `%-3d` formats to the left of a 3-space field. Please see [Format specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Also change to `if (i > 0 && (i + 1) % 7 == 0) printf("\n");` to print 7 columns per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I summed up the comments for the newcommers:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void makeTable (int, int);

int main (int argc, char * *argv, char * *envp) {
    makeTable(5, 35);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void makeTable(int start, int end) {
    for(int i = 0; i<=end-start; i++) {
        printf("%2d:%-3d", i+start, i+start-3);
        if(i>0 && (i+1) % 7 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```